# GFCI Receptacles

Tags: electrical

Several days ago a representative from the local power company did some exchange on our meter. He said the lights would go out for a moment and then be back and there would no harm done. It seemed that he was correct until we went into our bathroom to find out that both our GFCI receptacles were blown out by whatever had happened. What should I tell the power company when I call?

Comment: Do the GFI's reset? Or by "blown out" do you mean they're tripped and no longer reset?

Comment: Just explain to them what you just wrote here.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>When modern GFCI devices lose power, they revert to the tripped state.  Once power is restored, they'll have to be reset.</strike>

If the devices will not reset, tell the utility that the devices are no longer functional.

Comment: *"When modern GFCI devices lose power, they revert to the tripped state."* .............. I have not found this. I mainly use Eaton/Cooper or Leviton GFIs.

Comment: @SpeedyPetey if I'm not mistaken, the most recent UL specifications require this.  But as always, I could be wrong.

Comment: They are definitely self-test now, but I haven't had any that default to the tripped state. They also went up $3-4 because of it.